# Error:Array subscript is not an integer

Tags: c, arrays

```
int menu(int code)
{
    char item[7][30]={"Lunch/Dinner Set ","Breakfast Set","Kiddies Set",
                      "Promotion","Drink","French Fries","Dessert"};    
    int code_menu[7]={1,2,3,4,5,6,7};
    float price[7]={8.00,5.00,6.00,3.00,2.00,3.00,3.50};    
    int cnt;
    printf("\n\tCode\t\tItem\t\t\tPrice\n\n");

    for(cnt=0; cnt<5; cnt++) 
    {
     printf("\t%d\t\t%s\t\t\tRM%.2f\n", code_menu[cnt], menu[cnt], price[cnt]); 
    } 
}
```

Can anyone explain what have I done wrong with this line?

```
printf("\t%d\t\t%s\t\t\tRM%.2f\n", code_menu[cnt], menu[cnt],price[cnt]);
```

Comment: Where have you declared `menu` array ?

Comment: `menu` is the name of your function. try `code_menu[cnt]`

Comment: I think it should be `code_menu[cnt], item[cnt],price[cnt]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have an array named `menu`:

So, `menu[cnt]` is invalid to begin with.

Change that line to:

```
printf("\t%d\t\t%s\t\t\tRM%.2f\n", code_menu[cnt], item[cnt], price[cnt]);
```

Where `%d` is your `code_menu[cnt]`, `%s` is the `item[cnt]` and `%.2f` is the `price[cnt]`.

So, you basically need to switch `menu[cnt]` for `item[cnt]`.

Comment: thanks!! i just noticed it !! my teammate used different name in his version ......

Answer (score 2):

I suspect, you meant:

```
printf("\t%d\t\t%s\t\t\tRM%.2f\n", code_menu[cnt], item[cnt], price[cnt]);
```